# Java generating random objects [Homework]

Tags: java

Ok, I got the static error fixed.  Now I am just trying to find out why I'm getting the same entries for every object (ie same name, age, weight, etc).  Here is the code:

```
package classlab3b;

import classlab3B.BodyMassIndex;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author ccity
 */
public class ClassLab3B {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Please enter the number of people:");
        //asks user to input number of people
        int numberOfPeople;
        //declares integer variable for number of people
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        //creates system input scanner
        numberOfPeople = input.nextInt();
        //captures user input for number of people
        BodyMassIndex[] a = new BodyMassIndex[numberOfPeople];
        //creates an array of BodyMassIndex the size of numberOfPeople
        String name = loadRandomNames(a);
        //loads object with random name
        int age = loadRandomAges(a, numberOfPeople);
        //loads object with random age
        double weight = loadRandomWeights(a);
        //loads object with random weight
        double height = loadRandomHeights(a);
        //loads object with random height
        createObjectsToFillArray(a, name, age, weight, height, numberOfPeople);
        //creates "x" objects to fill the array
        double BMI = BodyMassIndex.getBodyMassIndex();
        //gets BMI from getBodyMassIndex method in BodyMassIndex.java
        String status = BodyMassIndex.getStatus();
        //gets status from getStatus method in BodyMassIndex.java
        //double BMI = BodyMassIndex.bmix.getBodyMassIndex();
        //String status = BodyMassIndex.bmix.getStatus();
        printArray(a, name, age, weight, height, BMI, status);
        //prints array


        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Current Population");
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Obese: " + BodyMassIndex.numberOfObese);
        System.out.println("Overweight: " + BodyMassIndex.numberOfOverweight);
        System.out.println("Normal: " + BodyMassIndex.numberOfNormal);
        System.out.println("Underweight: " + BodyMassIndex.numberOfUnderweight);
        System.out.println("================");
        System.out.println("Total: " + BodyMassIndex.totalNumberOfPeople);


    }

    public static void createObjectsToFillArray(BodyMassIndex[] data, String name, int age, double weight, double height, int numberOfPeople) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPeople; i++) 
            data[i] = new BodyMassIndex(name, age, weight, height);



        //creates new BodyMassIndex objects with generated variables from methods within
    }

    public static String loadRandomNames(BodyMassIndex[] data) {

        String[] arrayOfFirstNames = {"Joe", "Donna", "Ronald", "Sarah", "David", "Courtney", "Irwin", "Linda", "Michael", "Cindy", "Tom", "Rebekah", "Todd", "Tracy", "Peter", "Nicole", "Marcelo", "Jennifer", "Rick", "Andrea", "Bruce", "Jaclyn", "Doug", "Shirley", "Steve", "Liz", "Waldo", "Theresa", "Scott", "Colby", "Beth", "Larry", "Emily", "Paul", "Kate", "Sam", "Dianne", "Dustin", "Alethea", "Wayne", "Kristina", "Christian", "Danny", "Breya", "Andrew", "Alison", "Tim", "Mary", "Chris", "Susie", "Jeremy", "Willy", "Jessica", "Marcus", "Kelly", "Kyle", "Stephanie", "Isaiah", "Hillary", "Eric", "Julia", "Donald", "Meredith", "Kevin", "Leslie", "Blake", "Angela", "Cliff", "Debbie", "Dylan", "Erin", "Alex", "Monica", "Nathan", "Wendy", "Josh", "Megan", "Adam", "Michelle", "Carey", "Ashley", "Brian", "Jason", "Melanie", "Jim", "Monica", "Jamie", "Rhonda", "Steven", "Perry", "Byron", "Laura", "Harry", "Brooke", "Drew", "Vicki", "Gary", "Anita", "Felipe", "Josie"};
        String[] arrayOfLastNames = {"Smith", "Johnson", "Williams", "Jones", "Brown", "Davis", "Miller", "Wilson", "Moore", "Taylor", "Washington", "Jefferson", "Lincoln", "Hamilton", "Jackson", "Grant", "Franklin", "McKinley", "Cleveland", "Madison", "Chase", "Nicholson", "Fauver", "Doe", "Southard", "Schmidt", "Hodson", "McDonald", "Stickley", "Miller", "Combs", "Bohus", "Krippner", "Amtower", "Banks", "Wallace", "Bannister", "Dehaven", "Yost", "Still", "Timbrook", "Peters", "Vaught", "Shellhammer", "Andrews", "Krippner", "McAlister", "Wright", "Kensinger", "McClellan", "Ganoe", "Shiley", "Layman", "Gearhart", "Yost", "Kushnir", "Bush", "Lowder", "Connolly", "Lowman", "Terveen", "Staton", "Settle", "Tinsman", "Nichols", "Baker", "Walters", "Dawe", "Renner", "Michaels", "Faircloth", "Looker", "Hastings", "Vaughan", "Anderson", "Zimmerman", "Deere", "Daher", "Lauck", "Stottlemyer", "Clinton", "Obama", "Reagan", "Montgomery", "Pugh", "Gavis", "Clark", "Bowers"};

        String first = get(arrayOfFirstNames);
        String last = get(arrayOfLastNames);
        String name = first + " " + last;

        return name;
    }

    public static String get(String[] array) {
        Random generator = new Random();
        int rnd = generator.nextInt(array.length);
        return array[rnd];
    }

    public static int loadRandomAges(BodyMassIndex[] data, int numberOfPeople) {
        double min = 13;
        double max = 99;
        int age = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPeople; i++) 
            age = (int) randomInt(min, max);


        return age;
    }

    public static double randomInt(double min, double max) {

        double random = (double) ((max - min + 1) * Math.random() + min);
        return random;

    }

    public static double loadRandomWeights(BodyMassIndex[] data) {
        double min = 100;
        double max = 300;
        double weight = randomInt(min, max);
        for (int row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
        }
        return weight;
    }

    public static double loadRandomHeights(BodyMassIndex[] data) {
        double min = 55;
        double max = 80;
        double height = randomInt(min, max);
        for (int row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
        }
        return height;
    }

    public static void printArray(BodyMassIndex[] data, String name, int age, double weight, double height, double BMI, String status) {
        System.out.println("    Name           " + "Age    " + "Height    " + "Weight    " + "BMI    " + "Status");
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

            DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat();
            format.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
            format.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);


            System.out.println(name + "      " + age + "      " + format.format(height) + "    " + format.format(weight) + format.format(BMI) + "   " + status);
        }
    }
}
```

I should be getting random entries but I'm only getting one. Here is the output:

```
run:
Please enter the number of people:
4
    Name           Age    Height    Weight    BMI    Status
Courtney Anderson      81      79.64    155.0717.19   underweight
Courtney Anderson      81      79.64    155.0717.19   underweight
Courtney Anderson      81      79.64    155.0717.19   underweight
Courtney Anderson      81      79.64    155.0717.19   underweight

Current Population

Obese: 0
Overweight: 0
Normal: 0
Underweight: 1
================
Total: 4
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code ?

Comment: You don't really need that many comments ^^.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at weight for example, you generate a random weight as follows:

```
double weight = loadRandomWeights(a);
```

You then pass this to the code that fills the array:

```
createObjectsToFillArray(BodyMassIndex[] data, String name, int age, double weight, double height, int numberOfPeople)
```

Which then loops a number of times:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPeople; i++) 
    data[i] = new BodyMassIndex(name, age, weight, height);
```

So your problem is that each iteration of the loop is using the same random value.  You need to be generating a new random value *inside the loop* so each entry in the array gets a different value:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPeople; i++) {
    double weight = loadRandomWeights();
    ....
    data[i] = new BodyMassIndex(name, age, weight, height);
}
```

Obviously the same applies for the other values; you'll need to generate values for them inside the loop too.

And you have the same bug in your `printArray` method.  It's reprinting the same value rather than reading it off the objects you have created.  In that method read the values off your `BodyMassIndex` objects.

Also, I don't think your `loadRandomWeights()` method other similar ones needs a `data` parameter as you're neither writing to or reading from the array you pass in:

```
public static double loadRandomWeights(BodyMassIndex[] data) {
    double min = 100;
    double max = 300;
    double weight = randomInt(min, max);
    for (int row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
    }
    return weight;
}
```

This could just be:

```
public static double generateRandomWeight() {
    double min = 100;
    double max = 300;
    return randomInt(min, max);
}
```

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPeople; i++) 
    double weight = loadRandomWeights(a);
    data[i] = new BodyMassIndex(name, age, weight, height);
I get an error @ the second line "variable declaration not allowed here" ???

Comment: Sorry, forgot the brackets.  Fixed now.

Comment: Perhaps I am just an idiot... I don't know how I've gotten this far.  I am so far beyond frustration with this it isn't even funny.  Your 
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPeople; i++) {
    double weight = loadRandomWeights(a);
Is in the main method????

Comment: I can not get this to work... I'm probably doing something wrong but can not figure it out.

Comment: Put the calls to get the random values inside the loop in the `createObjectsToFillArray` method and also see my note about not needing to pass the array to the other methods.

Comment: I just tried that for weight and still all the same values.  Where is this note?

Comment: Ok, I see the note ... I just did all that and same result.  All weights are the same.

Comment: you have the same bug in your `printArray` method.  It's reprinting the same value rather than reading it off the objects you have created.  In that method read the values off your `BodyMassIndex` objects.

Comment: I think I got it... Thank you soooo much.  I can not tell you how grateful I am!

Answer (score 0):

Try for erach for loop:

```
    for (int row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
    double weight = randomInt(min, max);

    return weight;


    }
}
```

What about

Try for erach for loop:

```
    for (int row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
    double weight = randomInt(min, max);


    }
    return weight;


}
```

Comment: I have tried this but then I get an error that says it can't see the return statement.  And if I move the return statement outside of the first } then it doesn't know what the variable weight is.